# SSAS Filter Measure in Excel

Tags: excel, ssas, olap, cube

I have an SSAS 2008 cube that I'm connecting to from Excel 2010.

The cube works great, however some users have a business need to filter by a measure.  In Excel when you drag a measure to 'Report Filter' in the PivotTable Field list you get an error.

Say for example you have a measure that is the Total Time To Make Something.  Some users may only be interested in seeing data where that measure is greater than or less than some number of minutes.

Is there a way to accomplish this in Excel without modifying the cube in SSAS?

Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Drag measure to Values.
2. Drag dimension attribute to either rows or columns.
3. Assuming you drag dimension to rows, you'll see a drop down on the
   cell where it says "Row Labels".
4. Click on the drop down and select Value Filters and choose the
   filter you want.
5. Finally enter the filter criteria and click ok.

Comment: Thank you for the response Samuel.  But I think this describes how to filter the pivot table by the Dimension.  I'm wanting to filter by the Measure...any ideas if this can be done from Excel?

Comment: You can't add measures in filter per se. I strongly think, the above steps will accomplish what you're looking for. Sorry if it doesn't help :(

Comment: Thank you for following up Samuel, you're correct.  I didn't see the filter working b/c my dimension was a hierarchy date.  When I remove the hierarchy your recommended value filter did in fact work.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter using measures by using the Value Filters option instead of Value Label Filters. Label filters works for dimensions and Value filter is for measures.